# Mismatch in ViewExp::mapScreenToView

Tags: 3dsmax, maxscript

I am trying to implement the [How To ... Develop](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/search-result/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2015/ENU/MAXScript-Help/files/GUID-853014AC-9DC8-4F5C-B14B-3643E5925AD8-htm.html?_ga=1.142439162.973748673.1421306179) a Vertex Renderer using MAX SDK.

In the Maxscript version of [mapScreenToView](http://docs.autodesk.com/3DSMAX/15/ENU/MAXScript-Help/index.html?url=files/GUID-8AA71F9E-F4F0-4437-A44E-9683619E89DE.htm,topicNumber=d30e683762), We can specify , so that the calculation will be done based on the specified width and height. But this additional parameter is missing in the SDK version of [mapScreenToView](http://docs.autodesk.com/3DSMAX/15/ENU/3ds-Max-SDK-Programmer-Guide/index.html?url=cpp_ref/class_view_exp.html,topicNumber=cpp_ref_class_view_exp_html,hash=adfcad4a2e96f3d4fe2c163c6acf1d8a3).

Why  is the last parameter missing for SDK version of mapScreenToView
How can I achieve the same result of Maxscript in MaxSDK. Or in other words how can I specify an alternate width and height other than viewport width and height.

My final target is to find the position of a vertex after rendering it in the render window.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

MaxScript is not a 1-1 map to the SDK.  There are a lot of places where you will need to a bit more work to get the same affect in the SDK.

However, in this case things are just being a bit confusing.  There is very few cases where you would want to use pixel values from a window different sized than your own (the only possible use I can think of would where you are doing something with overscanning).

The arguments passed to the MaxScript function are the defaults, The C++ version will always use those values so just ignore that part of the tutorial.

(If you ever wanted to actually do this, you would scale your pixel values by the scale ratio from actual screen width/height to your desired screen width/height)

Comment: Actually, I tried scaling the final pixel values using the scale ratios. But  the result is not exactly the same as 3ds max rendering result. Depending on the viewport size final values is different. About specifying different window size, I want to find the position of a vertex in the render window when it is rendered from a specified viewport.  And size of my render window is different from viewport size.

Comment: Then use the viewExp from that viewport.  When you access the View, you can either get the active view or a specific one by index.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand the above comment correctly.  How can I solve the issue of difference in width/ height between viewport and render window by choosing a different viewExp